# Avoiding manual markdown code formatting

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, markdown, formatting

Feel free to edit the title of this question, I wasn't really sure what to call it.

In recent months I've started getting involved with SO a bit more and have been doing a fair bit of editing. One of the things I've noticed is that SO many people get code formatting wrong, specifically they try to add the four spaces which indicate a code block themselves, and do it badly, leading to things like this

int main() {

```
 int foo = bar;
```

}

or this

```
     public class Bar {
   }
```

I have found that when inputting code into a question, it is best to input the code without thinking about the markdown, then select the block and click the code button. Its also a lot less tedious.

It occurred to me that it wouldn't be difficult to pick up when users are trying to do the code block themselves (four consecutive spacebar presses when the cursor is at the start of a newline). The user could then be presented with the above advice, which would hopefully reduce the amount of time I spend deleting their formatting and starting again.

**Edit**

Although this question is indeed similar to the [post suggested as a duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304072/how-can-we-avoid-overhang-code-indentation), I am suggesting a very specific error that is distinct, in that it relates to attempts at *manually adding the four spaces necessary* to identify a text block as code. Although an alert similar to one suggested in one of the answers to that question would be an appropriate way of handling it, the method of detection would likely be different.

It is perfectly possible (though unlikely) that code like the above could have been copied and pasted from an editor. The solution I am suggesting would *not* flag this case, as it would look for repeated individual inputs of the whitespace character at certain positions.

Comment: Select and press CTRL-k?

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that, I'm just making the point that many people don't and a feature that spotted when people were trying to do it manually would be helpful.

Comment: Do people really read what's told them? That would be a new experience :P

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not everyone does, but if it suddenly appeared when they were typing as a 'warning' style message, many would.

Comment: Would be hard for the engine to decide if they're trying to post code actually. Is that worth the enormous effort for doing so? We have tons of reviewers sitting at the edit queue.

Comment: No it wouldn't, like I say; you don't need to pick up whether they are trying to post code, just look at the input behaviour. Anyone adding multiple consecutive spaces after a newline is obviously trying to indent the code block themselves